# How to help windows detect hidden drive after bios update?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios

After I reinstalled windows, I updated the bios using an update executable from the hp drivers website. It changed the legacy boot drives to raid, and I was unable to boot into windows, however I am still able to boot into linux on another disk. I tried reinstalling windows, but now I cannot get windows installation to detect any drives. What do I do?

I tried reformatting and unallocating the disk using gparted, with no success.

Comment: Restore your settings from before the update;

Comment: @Ramhound How do I restore the bios settings before the update? Thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound I found the bio settings. It was under Computer Step -> Change Sata Emulation. Thanks.